# Save multiple fields in one post meta array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom field for Hours, so I decided to make 7 inputs for the hours per weekday..

```
$week = [
        'monday',
        'tuesday',
        'wednesday',
        'thursday',
        'friday',
        'saturday',
        'sunday'
    ];

foreach ($week as $day) { 

        $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "$day", true ); ?>

        <div>
            <label for="<?php echo $day; ?>_hours" style="display: inline-block;float: left;clear: left;width: 250px;text-align: right;"><?php echo ucfirst($day); ?> Hours: </label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $day; ?>_hours" name="<?php echo $day; ?>" value="<?php echo "$value"; ?>" >
        </div>

<?php }
```

Now I have to persist this data..

```
foreach ($week as $day) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST["$day"] ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // Sanitize user input.
        $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["$day"] );

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "$day", $my_data );
    }
```

So this leaves me with 7 `post_meta` entries. Also, using this method, I have to duplicate my `$week[]` array in the saving and showing function. Could I just store the values as key => value pairings and reference just 1 `post_meta` object?

Comment: What we do at work. In our custom framework we have a method that you can just send an associative array to. Making your own function to do this seems ideal in your scenario. Easy to make, The key is the field and the value is the .. value

Comment: not sure if this is what you mean but if you name your inputs like this `<input name="week[<?php echo $day; ?>]">` than you can access like this on the receiving php script `$week = $_POST['week'];` and you'll get an array with the days of the week as the keys. so `$week['monday']` and `$week['tuesday']` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just save a single `meta_value` (as an array)? For example:

```
$week = array(
    'monday' => !empty( $_POST['monday'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['monday'] ) : '',
    'tuesday' => 'someval',
    'wednesday' => 'someval',
    'thursday' => 'someval',
    'friday' => 'someval',
    'saturday' => 'someval',
    'sunday' => 'someval'
);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'week', $week );
```

You can then grab all of the data with:

```
$week = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'week', true );  // retrieve an array of week data
```